# Openldap and ActiveDirectory authentication

Tags: ldap, openldap

Is it possible to connect to an OpenLDAP server as the active directory with this form 
" username@domain "
I have tested this form, it connects with active directory but with openLdap i have to put the full DN.

Does anyone has any idea how to modify my openLDAP to connect as AD if it's possible

Thanks.

Comment: OpenLDAP is an LDAP server. ActiveDirectory is another one. 'Connect to an OpenLDAP server as the active directory' is therefore meaningless. OpenLDAP does not support `username@domain` as a bind name. You have to first search the directory for the user with that mail address, and use that entry's DN as the bind-name.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use alternative bind names like the userPrincipalName (username@realm) with openLDAP, you need the rewrite/remap overlay [slapo-rwm](http://www.openldap.org/software/man.cgi?query=slapo-rwm&sektion=5&apropos=0&manpath=OpenLDAP%202.4-Release) coming with version 2.4.

A very simple example would be:

```
# Typed and not tested!

rwm-rewriteEngine   on

rwm-rewriteContext  addName
rwm-rewriteRule     "(.*)" "userPrincipalName=$1" ":"
rwm-rewriteMap      ldap upn2dn "ldap://host/dc=my,dc=org?dn?sub"

rwm-rewriteContext  bindDN
rwm-rewriteRule     ".*" "${upn2dn($0)}" ":@I"
```

EDIT

In reply to the question in your comment: LDAP as a protocol has no concept of uniqueness, it's a product feature.  With [OpenLDAP](http://www.openldap.org/software/man.cgi?query=slapo-unique&sektion=5&apropos=0&manpath=OpenLDAP%202.4-Release) for example, you can use the unique overlay to enforce uniqueness for certain attribute types in suitable backends. With [phpLDAPAdmin](http://phpldapadmin.sourceforge.net/wiki/index.php/Server:unique:attrs) you can configure the attribute types that shall be tested for uniqueness by that client.

Comment: Thanks for your responses, actually i'm looking for a way to find a unique attribute, my idea was to use the uid attribute because when i try to add value which is already used in another entry , phpldapadmin refuse to save it , contrary when i'm adding a user with java method, it acceps duplicate uid value.  ???

Comment: @AnasBenMansour You need the OpenLDAP `unique` overlay.

Answer (score 0):

If you wants to authenticate Openldap and AD users using same DN you need to add proxy to AD server from openldap server.

You need to use `back_ldap` module to make AD database as `subordinate` of Openldap database.

You can add custom attribute in openldap/ad for uniqueness of user mostly we find email attribute as common on both sides.